# Intent doesnt hand over variable from one class to another

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I am new to Android programming and tried to create a small App. I have a MainClass with one EditText and one TextField. EditText is for users to type in a number and the TextField shows the value of the input when clicking on the first button. The second button is for switching to the other class (MainClass2). Now i want to show the input number from EditText (that I defined as "number") in the next class MainClass2 in an empty TextField. I implemented an OnClickListener for the two different buttons mentioned in the MainClass (first screen). Since I only defined the input variable "number" when clicking the first button (cause "number" is then shown in the TextField as mentioned because it is only created via EditText when clicking the first button), "number" is not defined in the code of clicking the second button. Therefore I cant hand it over to the MainClass2 via Intent. Do you have any solutions for this? Thank you in advance. These are the codes for my Classes:

```
package com.example.teilnehmeranzahl;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        one.setOnClickListener(this); // calling onClick() method
        Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        two.setOnClickListener(this);

    } 

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // default method for handling onClick Events..
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String name2=editText2.getText().toString();
                int number=Integer.parseInt(name2);
                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

                textView.setText(String.valueOf(number));

                Random randomizer = new Random();
                int name = randomizer.nextInt(number+1);
                TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                if (name == 1 ) {
                    textView2.setText("Player 1");
                }

                if (name == 2 ) {
                    textView2.setText("Player 2");
                }


                break;

            case R.id.button2:


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("number",number); //here is the error cause number is not 
 defined, although it is..
                startActivity(intent);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }
```

}

And this is the code for MainClass2:

```
package com.example.teilnehmeranzahl;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        TextView textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String number = intent.getStringExtra("number");
       textView3.setText(number);

    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you define the number variable I see it only defined inside the scope of ```case R.id.button:```

Answer (score 1):

In `case R.id.button2:` you have not set the value of number. So it will give number undefined error. To solve this issue either you have to initialize number globally or get the value of number in `case R.id.button2:` also. Like

```
    case R.id.button2:

        EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String name2=editText2.getText().toString();
        int number=Integer.parseInt(name2);
        Intent intent = 
                    new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("number",number);
        startActivity(intent);

        break;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If i do it like your suggestions, i get errors cause it says number, editText2 and name2 are already defined in the scope (so in case R.id.button1). And I need to have it in case R.id.button1 too because I want to generate "number" first onclick of button1. Therefore i cant initialize number globally. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: I tried to initialize this part: "EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String name2=editText2.getText().toString();
    int number=Integer.parseInt(name2);" at the beginning after "public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {"
 but then the app crashes unfortunately. And if i insert it in here: "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)" number is not handed over to Button 1 onclick method